# line in legend symbol when adding segment in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, legend, segment

I am happy with the following code which achieves what I want on the example data:

```
   library(ggplot2)

   onecolony_20 <- data.frame(xdim250 = c(0.162, 0.162, 0.162, 0.162, 0.161,0.16, 0.159, 0.162, 0.162, 0.162, 0.161, 0.16,0.159,0.158,   0.159,   0.159,   0.159,   0.159,   0.159,   0.159,   0.159),ydim = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),3), u_in  = c(rep("1",7),rep("2",7),rep("3",7)))

   df <- data.frame(x1 = .159, x2 = 0.161, y1 = 1, y2 = 1)


   (plot_1_onecolony_20 <- ggplot(data = onecolony_20, aes(x = xdim250, y = ydim))+
          geom_point(aes( shape = u_in,color = u_in)) +
          scale_color_manual(values = c(2,4,1,1), breaks=c("1","2","3"))+
          scale_shape_manual( values = c( 4,17,16,1), breaks=c("1","2","3"))+
          theme(title = element_text(),
                axis.title = element_text(),
                axis.text = element_text(),
                axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black", size = rel(1.125)),
                legend.key   = element_rect(fill = "white"), 
                legend.position=c(0.45, 0.2), 
                legend.direction = "horizontal",
                legend.title = element_blank(),
                plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
                plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
)
```

But when I add a segment, lines appear in the symbols in the legend which I do not want:

```
   plot_1_onecolony_20 +
     geom_segment(aes( x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2, colour = "segment"), data = df)
```

How can I get rid of these lines in the legend symbols? Should I use the geom_segment code in a different way?

Comment: `+ geom_segment(....., show.legend = FALSE)` ?

Comment: yikes - that simple ?! how embarrassing - thanks so much! Exactly what I needed ..